# error: error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54)

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-clone

I am getting this error while cloning a repository.

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF 
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I am using git on the ubuntu terminal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+RPC+failed%3B+curl+56+GnuTLS+recv+error+54